# Div not centering well

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to create a lightbox efect for my website and I seem to have a problem with centerint the image here is my code:

```
<div id="lightbox">
    <img src="img/accrington-stanley.jpg" alt="Accrington Stanley" class="lightboximg"/>
</div>
  jQuery.fn.center = function () {
      this.css("position","absolute");
      this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");

      this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
      return this;
  } 

   var lightbox = $('div#lightbox');

            var lightboximg = $('img.lightboximg');

  portfolio.on("click","li" ,function(){
                var curent = $(this).attr("data-id");
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                    if(curent === attrValue){
                        for(var index in obj){
                                var attrName2 = index;
                                var attrValue2 = obj[index];
                                if(attrName2 === "img"){
                                    lightboximg.attr("src" , attrValue2);    
                                }     
                  }
                }

                lightbox.center().fadeIn();


            })
```

The source of the img.lightboximg changes on each click and thus the container width and height changes acording to the image size.The container doesn't center on the first click , but it centers on the second.The two loops are used only to change the src on img.lightboximg.

Another thing I don't understand is if I try to get the width and height of lightboximg variable it always returns 0.Why is that?
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and how to corect it in order to center div#lightbox?

**EDIT**:arr is an aray that contains a number of objects.In each object I have stored the src and other parameters

**EDIT**:I discoverd something very wierd while trying to make the code work.If I add an alert box in the click handler the container gets centered how is that related to anything?

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to post in a question. Could you please try  to narrow it down to a minimal example which shows the problematic behaviour? Short questions often get better answers.

Comment: The only thing that the loops do is change the source of lightbox img it's noths special about it

Comment: It's best not to use `alert()` and use `console.log` browser messages, as `alert()` can cause known interferences.

Comment: No matter what I used alert or consel.log when I try to get the width or height of the lightboximg variable it returns 0 this must be the reason why it's not centering corectly.I have tryed .width() , .height() , .outerwidth() , . outerheight() and they all return 0

Comment: With the alert it might just work, because by the time you are closing it, your object is then fully loaded and lightbox can get at the image dimensions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about a css approach?

```
.lightbox {
      position:absolute;
      left:50%;
      top:50%;
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
      margin-top:-100px;
      margin-left:-150px;
 }
```